# Javascript - Change lots of if statements by using class (ES6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, if-statement, design-patterns

I am using lots of if statements in my code now,
so I want to change by using class (ES6)

However, I am not much good at Javascript... so PLZ HELP ME..!

Prior code:

```
//example code
function first(){
  console.log('first scenario called');
}

function second(){
  console.log('second scenario called');
}

function third(){
  console.log('third scenario called');
}

state = 1;
if(state === 1){
  first();
}else if(state === 2){
  second();
}else if(state === 3){
  third();
}
//first scenario called
```

Changed code:

```
class Strategy {
    constructor(state) {
        this.state = state;

        if(this.state === 1){
          return first();
        }else if (val === 2){
          return second();
        }else if (val === 3){
          return third();
        }
    }

}

function first(){
  console.log('first scenario called');
}

function second(){
  console.log('second scenario called');
}

function third(){
  console.log('third scenario called');
}

let firstClass = new Strategy(1);
//first scenario called
```

This is my sample code..

Actually, I have almost 50+ if statments.
Is it right way to change lots of if statements???

Comment: No. You could use an array containing functions instead.

Comment: Using Switch or object with key to function mapping would be good

Comment: @str
Thank you for answering me :). I have some extra questions, If my if statements have not only === but includes() , how can I create an Object or a Map???

ex)
if(state === 'first'){
  first();
}else if(state === 'second'){
  second();
}else if(state.includes('num')){
  third();
}

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri
Thank you for answering me :). I have some extra questions, If my if statements have not only === but includes() , how can I create an Object or a Map???

ex)
if(state === 'first'){
  first();
}else if(state === 'second'){
  second();
}else if(state.includes('num')){
  third();
}

Comment: @hanswsw if your conditions are not exact matches but things like `state.includes('num')`, then you have no other choice than to use an `if` cascade. (Depending on the exact conditions, you might still be able to generalise into a loop, but that's it).

Comment: Do you actually need those `state` integers? Just store state as a reference to the function that you want to be called. Remember that JS is a functional language, the "strategy pattern" requires no objects at all but you can directly pass around functions.

Comment: @Bergi Then, you means don't I need class ??? Moreover, Is it a good way to make each functions by condition???

Comment: @hanswsw Yes, you wouldn't need a `class` at all if that's all what it is doing

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for answering me. This is my last question. If i execute same functions but different argument value on every condition, How about making a class and defining prototype method ??? Is it still better to not use class and just execute function on every statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a state as an integer and using that in an if or switch statement. Have strategies defined in their own classes. That way you can always expand, without having to modify one class that will grow out to a behemoth.

Why use seperate classes for extra functionality you might wonder when it's just one or two lines to execute?
Now you might have one or two lines, but in the future you might need to add a line here, a line there, add a for loop here with some more if statements here and there and you'll need a few variables to log a state and your 20 line program ends up as a 200-2000 line behemoth with a lots of ifs and elses and possibly some conflicting states due to a typo in similarly named variables. These things tend to grow.

By having seperation of concerns(google that) you can just add functionality in individual classes without ever having to worry that the functionality overlaps any other and you can add other things any time you want by having one global strategist class that manages the strategies. The strategies have their own states, one time runners, interval runners, xhr handlers, etc... without effecting the state of the main strategist. It keeps your code clear and you will be able to see what code causes what. When you have a  200 line behemoth in 6 months it becomes harder because one thing belongs to one state needs to be linked to the correct if statement and you might end up updating it in another if statement.

Also by having individual classes you can automate testing what they do which makes it easier for you to check all code is still working as expected.

```
class Strategist {

    constructor() {
        this.strategies = {};
        this.activeStrategy = -1;
        this.strategy = null;
    }

    registerStrategy(strategy) {
         this.strategies[strategy.getId()] = strategy;
    }
    setStrategy(id) {
        if(this.activeStrategy != -1) {
            if(this.strategies.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                this.activeStrategy = id;
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("No such strategy was registered!");
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Another strategy is already active!");
        }
    }
    run() {
        this.strategies[ activeStrategy ].run();
    }
    public function stop() {
        this.strategies[ this.activeStrategy ].stop();
        this.strategies[ activeStrategy ].reset();
        this.activeStrategy = -1;
    }
}
```

Then have strategies defined. first a global parent class.

```
   class Strategy {
       constructor(external_id) {
          this.id = external_id;
       }
       get getId() {
          return this.id;
       }
       run(){};
       stop(){};
       reset(){};
   }
```

Then the actual strategies. what needs to happen you define here.

```
class StrategyFirst extends Strategy {
        run() {
            // do something
        }
        stop() {
            // stop doing stuff
        }
        reset() {
             // reset state
        }
   }

   class StrategySecond extends Strategy {
        run() {
            // do something
        }
        stop() {
            // stop doing stuff
        }
        reset() {
             // reset state
        }
   }
```

Then register them to the strategiest

```
strategist = new Strategist();
strategist.registerStrategy(new StrategyFirst("destroy all humans"));
strategist.registerStrategy(new StrategySecond("pluck a flower"));
```

then when something has happened and you need to run it you can call upon your strategist to decide.

```
 strategist.setStrategy("pluck a flower");
```

Below in the snippet is a small implementation example of how this would work in the real world ish.

```js
class Strategist {

    constructor() {
        this.strategies = {};
        this.activeStrategy = -1;
        this.strategy = null;
    }

    registerStrategy(strategy) {
         this.strategies[strategy.getId()] = strategy;
    }
    setStrategy(id) {
        if(this.activeStrategy === -1) {
            if(this.strategies.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                this.activeStrategy = id;
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("No such strategy was registered!");
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Another strategy is already active!");
        }
    }
    run() {
        this.strategies[ this.activeStrategy ].run();
    }
    stop() {
        this.strategies[ this.activeStrategy ].stop();
        this.strategies[ this.activeStrategy ].reset();
        this.activeStrategy = -1;
    }
}
   class Strategy {
       constructor(external_id) {
          this.id = external_id;
       }
       getId() {
          return this.id;
       }
       run(){};
       stop(){};
       reset(){};
   }
   
   class StrategyFirst extends Strategy {
        run() {
            if(!this.isRunning) {
                this.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                    window.alert("BOOOOM! Another one bites the dust, dum dum dum");
                }, 3000);
                this.isRunning = true;
             }
        }
        stop() {
            window.clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
        reset() {
             this.interval = null;
             this.isRunning = false;
        }
   }

   class StrategySecond extends Strategy {
        run() {
            if(!this.isRunning) {
                this.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                    window.alert("Oooh, look a pretty flower *pluck*");
                }, 3000);
                this.isRunning = true;
             }
        }
        stop() {
            window.clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
        reset() {
             this.interval = null;
             this.isRunning = false;
        }
   }
   
strategist = new Strategist();
strategist.registerStrategy(new StrategyFirst("destroy all humans"));
strategist.registerStrategy(new StrategySecond("pluck a flower"));

document.getElementById("execute").addEventListener('click',function() {
    var select = document.getElementById('fate');
    strategist.setStrategy(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
    strategist.run();
});
document.getElementById("halt").addEventListener('click',function() {
    strategist.stop();
});
```

```html
<select id="fate">
   <option value="destroy all humans">Destroy humans</option>
   <option value="pluck a flower">Destroy flowers</option>
 </select>
 <button id="execute">Execute fate</button>
 <button id="halt">Interrupt fate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Quick and Dirty – Not the preferred way

Just create a map where the key gives you the correct function:

```
this.strategies = {
    1: this.first,
    2: this.second,
    3: this.third
}
```

and then search the function and execute it:

```
execute(value) {
    this.strategies[value] == null
        ? console.log("this strategy does not exist")
        : this.strategies[value]()
}
```

### A full working Example

```js
class Strategy {

    constructor(value) {
        this.strategies = {
            1: this.first,
            2: this.second,
            3: this.third
        }

        this.execute(value)

    }

    execute(value) {
        this.strategies[value] == null
            ? console.log("this strategy does not exist")
            : this.strategies[value]()
    }

    first() {
        console.log('first scenario called');
    }

    second() {
        console.log('second scenario called');
    }

    third() {
        console.log('third scenario called');
    }
}

new Strategy(0);
new Strategy(1);
new Strategy(2);
new Strategy(3);
```

## The Factory-Patter – The Preferred way

The class `Strategy`is doing two thinks:

- it *looks* for the right method
- it *executes* the right method

it *looks* for the right method. The lookup think should be in the class `StrategyFacotry` and the execution should handle someone but not the `StrategyFacotry`.

little hint: to lookup the right strategy uses the quick and dirty way from above :)

I put the different strategies into separate classes. Important is that these functions have to share the same interface. In my example they all have to implement the function `execute`. If you have only little functions you can it do with a lamda too.

```js
class StrategyFactory {

    constructor() {
        this.strategies = {
            1: new PowerfullStrategy(),
            2: new WeakStrategy(),
        }
    }

    get(value) {
        return this.strategies[value] == null
            ? new DefaultStrategy()
            : this.strategies[value]
    }
}

class DefaultStrategy {
    excecute() {
        console.log("this strategy does not exist")
    }
}

class PowerfullStrategy {
    excecute() {
        // do some
        // calculaion here ..
        console.log("I AM THE POWERFULL STRATEGY")
    }
}


class WeakStrategy {
    excecute() {
        // do some
        // calculaion here ..
        console.log("i am the waek strategy")
    }
}

const factory = new StrategyFactory()
const strategy = factory.get(1)
const otherStrategy = factory.get(1000)

strategy.excecute()
otherStrategy.excecute()
```